# Loading an image to an OpenGL texture using Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, opengl

This seems like it should be something that's easy to do, but I can't seem to find a source out there to tell me how to do it.  I would like to load a texture from an image file into my shader.  I'm trying to stick as close to the core profile as possible in OpenGL 3.3, although I understand a lot of things are still not implemented in OS X.  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm still pretty new to OpenGL, so descriptiveness would help out greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know how to work with cocoa, but, there is another library which may help you a lot. It's name is DevIL. you can google and download it. It worked for me ;)

Comment: Also, note that it is open-source.

Comment: That's what I needed. I'm just really surprised there's not an easy Cocoa way to do it. It seems like a big omission. Thanks.

Comment: Right, it is not simple. Sample codes are available in it's website. If you need i will send one to you.